Mass Calculation in Effective Dilaton-Gravity Action for General Asymptotic Flat Metric
According to eq.(21) in the article, for dilaton gravity action:
$$I = \frac{1}{2\kappa^2}\int d^Dx\sqrt{-g}e^{-2\Phi}\left[R-2\Lambda + 4\partial_{\mu}\Phi\partial^\mu\Phi-\frac{1}{12}H^{\alpha\mu\nu}H_{\alpha \mu \nu} \right]$$
The mass calculation is given by the following formula:
$$M=\frac{1}{2\kappa^2}\oint_{S^\infty}e^{-2\Phi}\left[-\partial_i\gamma_{tt}+\partial^\mu\gamma _{\mu i}-\partial_i\gamma-2\gamma_{i\mu}\partial^\mu\Phi\right]dS^i $$
Where $t$ is a temporal coordinate, $\gamma_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}-\eta_{\mu\nu}$ for a metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ given in coordinates which asymptotically converge to Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$. Morover, $\gamma=\det(\gamma_{\mu\nu})$ and the integration is done on the asymptotic sphere in the infinity with a normal area measure $dS^i$.
My question is regarding of how this formula modified when the given metric is asymptotically flat but not tends to the Minkowski metric, for example consdier the following stationary metric in 2+1 dimesions:
$$ds^2 = g_{rr}(r)dr^2+g_{tt}(r)dt^2+g_{\theta\theta}(r)d\theta^2+2g_{t\theta}(r)dtd\theta$$
Such that it is asymptotically flat but non-diagonal when $r\to\infty$
$$ds^2\Big|_{r\to\infty}=g_{rr}^{\infty}dr^2+g^{\infty}_{tt}dt^2+g^{\infty}_{\theta\theta}d\theta^2+2g^{\infty}_{t\theta}dtd\theta$$
Where:
$$g_{rr}^{\infty},g^{\infty}_{tt},g^{\infty}_{\theta\theta},g^{\infty}_{t\theta} = const\ne 0$$
